# How to generate return value type and variable assignment in Eclipse java editor?

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

If I have  a statement like this  " `EntitiesProvider.getEntities();`

Any idea how to "generate" the assignment to variable of return Type ?

so that this would be generated `Map<String, Entity> hashMap =`

this is the result :

```
Map<String, Entity> hashMap = EntitiesProvider.getEntities();
```

It is similar to ctrl + 1  and Change type,  if it returns different Type that you already have there.

I find myself doing myself manually very often...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`Ctrl+2, L` is one option, and the other is `Alt+Shift+L` when the desired statement is selected. The popup will appear allowing to set variable name & few additional options (e.g., "Replace occurrences of the selected expression with references to the local variable").

I prefer `Alt+Shift+L` because it allows marking specific part of the line for variable extraction.

.. and here's a simple example:

```
..
new FileInputStream(new File("test.txt"));
..
```

You can select the whole line to assign it to `FileInputStream` variable, or you can 'extract' `new File("test.txt")`, or even String expression `"test.txt"`.

P.S. Sometimes I wish it would be able to let me choose supertype from combo box in a pop-up, e.g. `InputStream` in this specific example.

Answer (score 7):

**CTRL=2,L** will do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

What is wrong with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>. With <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd>/<kbd>↑</kbd> ?

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+L brings a popup for all other Shortcuts, if you sometime search for another.

Answer (score 0):

CTRL+2,L and ALT+CTRL+L can get the job done for you.

CTRL+2 is a short key to a quick assist tool which can perform

---

1. assigning to a **F**ield (F)
2. assigning to a **L**ocal variable (L)
3. extracting **M**ethod (M)
4. **R**enaming in file (R)

you can press any key of these four as u need it.